# Prove There is a set for which {1}∈X and {1}⊆X?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am new to proof I found this question in worksheet I have no idea how to do it? Can anyone willing explain it to it would much appreciated. this question Prove There is a set for which {1}∈X and {1}⊆X?

This is what I have tired:
`suppose {1}EX` by definition it means 1 is an element of x hence {1} is subset of X therefore  {1}∈X and {1}⊆X is true

Comment: The set $X = \{1,\{1\}\}$ will work.

Comment: $$X= \{1, \{ 1\} \}$$ and the proof is complete.

Comment: $\{1\} \in X$ means that {1} is an element of x, not that 1 is an element of x.

Comment: $\{1\}\in X$ does not mean $1 \in X$.  .... This statement is *not* to prove $\{1\}\in X \implies \{1\}\subseteq X$.   That statement simply isn't true. (The set $X=\{\{1\}\}$ is a counterexampble  $\{1\} \in X$ but $1 \not \in X$ so $\{1\}\not \subset X$.)... The statement is just to prove both are *possible* and there is such a set.  We need $\{x\} \in X$. and we nee $\{1\}\subset X$ so we need $1 \in X$.  That's just take any set with those elements.  Take $\{1, \{x\}\}=X$.  That will do.

Comment: Sorry I bit confused on the part say  x is element of X

Comment: Just bear in mind a set $\{a\}$ is a different thing than $a$. ANd that if *set* $\{a,b,c,d\} \in X$ that does *NOT* mean the elements within the set $a,b,c,d$ are elements of the set.  Because the *set* is a different thing that its elements.  And it's the *set*, not the elements, that are in $X$.  So $1$ and $\{1\}$ are not the same thing so $\{1\} \in X \not \implies 1\in X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what is being asked.  It isn't asking that one statement implies the other.  That would be false.  You can certainly have $1$ in a set without having $\{1\}$ in the set (and vice versa).

(You statement $\{1\} \in X$ implies $1$ is an element of $X$ is just plain wrong.  The set $\{1\}$ is not the same thing as the number $1$ and the set $\{1\}$ being an element of $X$ will not mean the number $1$ will be an element.)

$\{1\} \in X$ means that $\{1\}$ (the set, not $1$ itself) is in the set $X$.  SO if we were to list out all the elements of $X$ as $X$ contains: $......., \{1\}........$ then $\{1\}$ will be one of them.

And $\{1\}\subset X$ means $\{1\}$ is as subset of $X$.  That means if we list the elements of $\{1\}$, that is $\{1\}$ contains the following elements:  $1$; that is all.... then all the  element of $\{1\}$ will also be an element of $X$.  So if we list out all the elements of $X$ as: $......, 1,.....$ then $1$ will be in there because $1$ is in $\{1\}$.

All you are being asked is that there is a set with both the elements $\color{blue}{\{1\}}$ and $\color{red}1$ in it.

So if we listed out all the elements of $X$ it would have: $......., \color{blue}{\{1\}},.........,\color{red}1,.....$ in it.

And that should be trivial: just *put* them in a set.  $X= \{  \color{blue}{\{1\}} ,\color{red}1\}$

That's it.

Of course you need axioms that sets of elements exist for the elements you want, I'm not up an my set theory axioms but I believe there is one that states just that.... *goes off to google*.... Ah, yes... that is the Axiom of Specification.

If we want to get formal:

$\emptyset$ exists.

So by Axiom of Specification. $1 := \{\emptyset\}$ exists.

And as $1$ exists, by Axiom of Specification $\{1\}$ exists.

So we have $1$ and $\{1\}$ exists.  So for the third time by Axiom of Specification $X:=\{1, \{1\}\}$ exists.

And $1 \in X$. So $\{1\} \subseteq X$.  And $\{1\} \in X$.

So the statements hold for $X$.  That proves it.

Comment: Thank man. This really help man.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Sets can contain other sets! (It would be more helpful if you could tell us what you tried.)

Comment: I have made changes to the answer I have shown what I have tried